# CXProviderDelegate methods are not triggered

Tags: ios, objective-c, callkit

I am trying to integrate CallKit into my Voip app. I referred to the SpeakerBox sample code from Apple WWDC. I created a ProviderDelegate class and I am able to see the incoming call UI after calling `reportNewIncomingCall` method.

But when I tap on the "Answer"/"End" button, the respective provider delegates are not fired. What could be wrong here?

Please note that "`providerDidBegin`" is called when I instantiate the `CallProviderDelegate`.

```
@implementation CallProviderDelegate

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _providerConfiguration = [self getProviderConfiguration];
        _provider = [[CXProvider alloc] initWithConfiguration:_providerConfiguration];
        [_provider setDelegate:self queue:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)providerDidBegin:(CXProvider *)provider {
   // this is getting called
}

- (void)provider:(CXProvider *)provider performAnswerCallAction:(CXAnswerCallAction *)action {
  // this is not getting called when the Answer button is pressed
}

- (void)reportNewIncomingCallWithUUID:(nonnull NSUUID *)UUID handle:(nonnull NSString *)handle
                           completion:(nullable void (^)(NSError *_Nullable error))completion {

    CXCallUpdate *update = [[CXCallUpdate alloc] init];
    update.remoteHandle = [[CXHandle alloc] initWithType:CXHandleTypePhoneNumber value:handle];
    update.hasVideo = NO;

    [_provider reportNewIncomingCallWithUUID:UUID update:update completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        completion(error);
    }]; 
}
```

In Caller Class:

```
CallProviderDelegate *providerDelegate = [[CallProviderDelegate alloc] init];
[providerDelegate reportNewIncomingCallWithUUID:[NSUUID UUID] handle:@"Raj" completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
            //
 }];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your "caller" class, i.e. the code in which you instantiate the `CallProviderDelegate` class and assign it to the `providerDelegate` variable, are you storing the `providerDelegate` object reference in an instance variable or property? If it is only being assigned to a temporary local variable, then the `CallProviderDelegate` object will be deallocated after the calling method finishes executing, and if the `CallProviderDelegate` object is deallocated then no further CXProvider delegate messages will be delivered.

I'd check that your `CallProviderDelegate` object is not being accidentally deallocated first.

Comment: Yes, I made this exact mistake and fixed it later. Forgot to update the thread. Thanks for taking the time to answer Stuart.

Comment: @Rajavelu : can you please let me know how can you bring the CallKit UI front of the APp?

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati You need to call 'reportNewIncomingCall' method from the Provider delegate.

Comment: You can see this and the SpeakerBox sample code. https://developer.apple.com/reference/callkit/cxprovider/1930694-reportnewincomingcall

Comment: @Rajavelu - I have implemented this method , still after pressing green button , callkit ui is hiding behind main App UI. can you please help me out with this

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati Do you have any code snippet that you can show?

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati Sorry I have been away for a while. Hope you have got them working by now.

Comment: I am facing problem of hiding callkit behind the my voip app. Did any one found the solution for this?